# Web API parameter binding custom object with localized values

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

We are currently translating a massive enterprise application to support the French language and we have a minor issue when passing json currency values to our Web API.

The API parameter is just using the default  attribute and our custom object has always been populated from the json input correctly without any issues.

However since French supports a comma within a currency value (as the decimal), the value is sent by Angular as a String, and is assigned to a Double property on the API side, the comma is just removed so instead of "1,23" it becomes "123" when we're wanting 1.23 assigned to the Double property.

The json being sent to the server is valid as French currency
    `"EstimateValue": "2,22",`

However when the framework does the complex object translation it just seems to remove the comma and leaves the raw digits: 222

I've seen articles about parameter binding or implementing the Parse() method, however the object is very large and 99% of it works as-is, I'm wondering if there is a way to somehow intercept the binding of just this one property?

Comment: I Think you need to use a pipe to transform the api data courrency

Comment: Can you elaborate on that at all?